# droppable not working with $.post created elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

why are elements created by using $.post functionality not recognized by jquery ui droppable functionality?

when i create the following line directly i can drop things on it:

```
echo '<tr class="droptarget"><td>test</td></tr>';
```

but when the same line is placed in a php file and is received as the result of a $.post call i cannot access the droptarget via jquery.

```
$.post('test.php', function(data) {
  $('#ausgabe').html(data);
  calculate();
});
```

this is the according jquery code:

```
$('.element').draggable({
  appendTo: 'body',
  revert: 'invalid', 
  helper: 'clone'
});
$('.droptarget').droppable({
  accept: '.element',
  drop: function(event,ui) {
    alert('hallo');
  }
});
```

for clickable elements created by a $.post call i know i must use the following :
    $('.element').on('click','.remove',function(e)...

but how is this done for droppable functionality??

Comment: did you call .droppable on the new elements after you added them?

Comment: seems as exactly that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just a second later found this solution:

```
$.post('test.php', { fn: '' }, function(data) {
  $('#ausgabe').html(data);
  $('.droptarget').droppable({
    accept: '.zutat',
    activeClass: 'drop-active',
    hoverClass: 'drop-hover',
    drop: function(event,ui) {
      alert('hallo');
    }
  });
});
```

maybe this helps others...